# Richedit and remove all text from a person content

Tags: delphi

So I got talking to one of my people and there feel it would be a good idea to hash out all the current chat that was sent by a blocked person a bit like how TwitchTV chat works if person is blocked it would remove all the persons chats and replace with ***

now it was late when we were taking so my brain don't work so well at 5am :D but now am up I been thinking even more on how to do this I guess it would have to be string list with current incoming chat then search for the persons name and then remove all the text after persons name

chat format is as so

> Simon: my test message

so after being muted the chat out come would look like

> Simon: ** **** *******

any one ever done this at all seams very complex

Thanks

Comment: If you already have an incoming stream in a TSTringList, why not start building your code. Then, if it does not work, ask help here **with code**. That is how SO works. Right now we have **no** idea what you are talking about, what chat, what code you already have, etc.

Comment: What is the question? It's your program. Put whatever you like in the edit control.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly what you want to do, it should actually be straightforward;

Forget the TRichEdit for a moment, because the solution to this problem is about data structures, and the RichEdit is merely a way of surfacing what you want in your GUI.

Suppose you have a TStringList, ChatMessages, to which you append a user's name and
what they've typed, and another TStringList, Users, which contains a list of their names.

Then, to achieve the functionality you want, you need to keep track of "who said what",
and the Objects property of the ChatMessages TStringList can be used for that.

So, you might have a couple of methods like this:

```
function TForm1.GetUserID(const UserName : String) : Integer;
begin
  Result := Users.IndexOf(UserName) + 1;
  if Result = 0 then begin
    Users.Add(UserName);
    Result := Users.IndexOf(UserName) + 1;
  end;
  Assert(Result > 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddChatMsg(UserName, Msg : String);
var
  UserID : Integer;
begin
  UserID := GetUserID(UserName);
  ChatMessages.Add('');
  ChatMessages.AddObject(UserName + ': ' + Msg, TObject(UserID));
end;
```

and another procedure to periodically update the RichEdit's contents
from ChatMessages.

Then, when you want to "twit" a user, you can search through ChatMessage's Objects
looking for their ID number.  You can then replace what follows in their
name-tag lines by asterisks, likewise in the following lines until you find
another user's user-ID in the objects or reach the end of ChatMessages.  Coding of that is left as an exercise for the reader.

It doesn't matter whether you do the asterisks in the ChatMessage text, or as you
copy its text into the richEdit, except on course that if you do it in the RichEdit
you can "untwit" the user later by refreshing it from ChatMessages without the asterisk substitution.

Note that GetUserID above bases the user's ID on their index in the Users list (plus 1 to avoid any user having a UserID of zero, which would clash with lines where AddObject was not used).  Because of that it is important that existing user's indexes don't change when a user is added to the list.  So, you would not want the Users list to be sorted (or, if you need that, you'd need to derive a UserID in a different way).

Also, I've stored numbers in the stringlist's Objects property purely to make this code as simple as possible for illustration purposes.  In a real-world solution, you would want to use a "cleaner" way to do this, and the obvious way to do this is to have a TUser class with properties such as name, userid and "twit" flag and some kind of user-container class, etc, but the implementational details of those would just get in the way if included here.  Once you have a TUser class, of course, then the thing to do would be to store a user's TUser instance in the stringlist's Objects property.

Comment: If you would use a real object the update process becomes much more easier and cleaner. IMHO fake instances from an integer are one of the worst patterns I saw

Comment: @SirRufo: Thank you for those kind words.  Seriously, I know what you mean, personally I wouldn't uses the Objects property to store numbers - the idea makes my toes curl the same way as when I see the Tag property being used.  So,  I've added a para to the answer of my answer to make it clear that I've only done it the way I have for simplicity of illustration.  But I think it distracts a bit from the main pont of my answer, which is that what the OP apparently wants is actually fairly simple to do, but a TRichEdit isn't the place to start.

Comment: IMData.UserID  it returns the usersname string name 

and i just add normal richline.lines.add(IMData.UserID +': '+ Message):

Message is just a string direct from client to server to other clients no  fancy workings

Comment: I realise that's what you might be doing at the moment, but if you want a useful solution to the q you asked, you need to do something like I describe.  Either that, or just search the text in the richedit for every occurrence of the user's name and replace everything that follows up to the next user's message by asterisks.  Up to you.

Comment: little hard to ex-plane it I would need to talk to you for you to understand it better